# How to write a scala spark code to connect to Multiple cloud platforms(Azure,AWS) with Design Pattern or OOP

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oop, design-patterns, azure-blob-storage

I want to write a spark Scala code in GenericWay where it can connect to azure Blob storage or S3 or some other storage in another cloud to read the data. Want to write it as an Extendable and Wrapper way.

Expectation : implementation using design pattern or OOPs concepts.

Thoughts: Correct me If iam Wrong

```
CloudService as Interface;
implementation of cloudService as Azure
implementation of cloudService as AWS S3
implementation of cloudService as AWS Redshift

Calling Interface will dynamically invoke related implementation.
```

Suggest Other Ways or Please extend my Thoughts

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could have a look at [Benji](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/) (I'm contributor of) which provides abstraction for Object storage operations (now for S3/Google, planned for Azure).

Comment: for S3 you can use https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Strategy pattern. 
Suppose the succession of operations is connect, read and cleanup (free resources, close connections and so on).

Then you have

```
trait CloudService {
    def connect()
    def read()
    def cleanup()

}
```

with implementations for every cloud system you use. This is the Strategy.

```
class AWSCloudService extends CloudService {
    ...

}
```

This are the concrete Strategy implementation. 
To use them, you need a Context, which is a class that  will get a Strategy implementation and call the methods:

class CloudReader {

```
def readFromCloud(  service : CloudService ) {
    service.connect()
    service.read()
    service.cleanup() 
}
```

}

For more information on the Strategy desing pattern:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Suppose I'm getting config as s3 .how to call relevant implementation ? 
if I call trait will trait handles what to call .?

Comment: The trait only defines the operations. To call the Concrete Strategy implementations you need something like a factory.

Comment: exactly expecting Factory pattern